# PHP break script of option disable

Tags: php, directadmin

In DirectAdmin I have the option:
[image]

This option variable name:`installwp`

When option is selected then below script is running:

```
 #check custom pkg item installwp
 
if [[ $installwp == 'OFF' ]]; then
  exit 0;
else
 
#set up DB variables
dbpass=$(openssl rand -hex 6) > /dev/null
ext=$(openssl rand -hex 2) > /dev/null
dbuser="wp${ext}"    # do not include the username_ for dataskq here as DA adds this 
wpconfigdbuser="${username}_wp${ext}"
wpadminpass=$(openssl rand -hex 6) > /dev/null
 
# install wp
if [ -f /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.php ]; then 
 echo "WARNING: There appears to be an index file already located in this directory, which indicates that an installation is already present! Empty the directory before running the script again."
 exit 
else
 
 #Disable DAs index.html file
 if [ -f /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.html ]; then
  mv /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.html{,.bak}
 fi
```

When option is not selected then we exit script:

```
if [[ $installwp == 'OFF' ]]; then
  exit 0;
```

OK, this works fine.

Now we add second option:
[image]

This second option have variable: `installwptwentytwenty`.

And now I need first whole code break and run second code for second option. Second option have name `installwptwentytwenty`.

So I try use break first variable `installwp` and run `installwptwentytwenty`. So I try  add  below code:

```
**** THIS CODE NOW WE NEED TO SKIP*************
    #check custom pkg item installwp
     
    if [[ $installwp == 'OFF' ]]; then
      break 0;
    else
     
    #set up DB variables
    dbpass=$(openssl rand -hex 6) > /dev/null
    ext=$(openssl rand -hex 2) > /dev/null
    dbuser="wp${ext}"    # do not include the username_ for dataskq here as DA adds this 
    wpconfigdbuser="${username}_wp${ext}"
    wpadminpass=$(openssl rand -hex 6) > /dev/null
     
    # install wp
    if [ -f /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.php ]; then 
     echo "WARNING: There appears to be an index file already located in this directory, which indicates that an installation is already present! Empty the directory before running the script again."
     exit 
    else
     
     #Disable DAs index.html file
     if [ -f /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.html ]; then
      mv /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.html{,.bak}
     fi

**** THIS CODE NOW WE NEED TO RUN IF SECOND OPTION IS SELECT*************
    #check custom pkg item installwp
     
    if [[ $installwptwentytwenty == 'OFF' ]]; then
      exit 0;
    else
     
    #set up DB variables
    dbpass=$(openssl rand -hex 6) > /dev/null
    ext=$(openssl rand -hex 2) > /dev/null
    dbuser="wp${ext}"    # do not include the username_ for dataskq here as DA adds this 
    wpconfigdbuser="${username}_wp${ext}"
    wpadminpass=$(openssl rand -hex 6) > /dev/null
     
    # install wp
    if [ -f /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.php ]; then 
     echo "WARNING: There appears to be an index file already located in this directory, which indicates that an installation is already present! Empty the directory before running the script again."
     exit 
    else
     
     #Disable DAs index.html file
     if [ -f /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.html ]; then
      mv /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain/index.html{,.bak}
     fi
```

But now it doesn't work,  nothing happens.

I checked in log error:

```
line 121: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**Please note:** Currently, the two codes for the two options look the same. But in fact, two other operations will be performed in the future so we need full separate this.